# Is the projectivization of a variety well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given an affine variety $X$ embedded in affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$, there is a simple-minded construction which associates a projective variety $\mathbb{P}(X) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, as follows. If $I \subseteq k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ is the ideal defining $X$, then $\mathbb{P}(X)$ is defined by the homogeneous ideal $\mathbb{P}(I)\subseteq k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$, where if $f = \sum a_{i_1,\dots,i_k} x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_k^{i_k} \in I$, then $\tilde{f} = \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k} x_0^{D - i_1 - \dots - i_k} x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_k^{i_k} \in \mathbb{P}(I)$ for $D$ large enough to make all exponents positive.

This is a well-defined operation turning an affine variety (or more generally, affine algebraic set) in $\mathbb{A}^n$ into one in $\mathbb{P}^n$. But it would appear to depend on the embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{A}^n$. Is this the case? That is, if I have two isomorphic subvarieties $X,X' \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n, X \cong X'$, are the resulting projectivizations $\mathbb{P}(X), \mathbb{P}(X')$ necessarily isomorphic? I suspect not, but I don't have a counterexample.

A little googling turns up something called the [$\mathbf{Proj}$ construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proj_construction) which may be relevant, but it apparently requires a graded ring as input, and the function algebra of $X$ will not typically be graded as far as I can see.

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate question which I should have found, and the answers are similar, but user90219's answer is clearer to me, somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, and I think the following example works:  Consider $C_1$ given by $y=x$ and $C_2$ given $y=x^3$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. Then both their coordinate rings are isomorphic to $k[x]$ so $C_1$ and $C_2$ are isomorphic (to $\mathbb{A}^1$). In $\mathbb{P}^2$ the equations become $y=x$ and $yz^2=x^3$, and so $\mathbb{P}(C_1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, while $\mathbb{P}(C_2)$ is a singular curve (because in the coordinate patch where $y\neq 0$, the equation becomes $z^2=x^3$ which is singular at $x=0, z=0$) and so $\mathbb{P}(C_2)$ can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually surprising to me to realize that $y=x^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. I think I was under the false impression that $y=x^2$ was _not_ isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, so I probably wouldn't have tried this example!